# how to refresh a particular div in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know how to refresh a particular div in a page, i dont want to load whole page but one certain div. is it posible?

Comment: See ["How to refresh <DIV>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989625/how-to-refresh-div).

Comment: use ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

While I'm still in the process of learning myself, I think what you're essentially talking about is AJAX. The jQuery library gives you a number of ways to make AJAX calls, some high level, some low level. Search the jQuery home page for .load() for a high level solution and .ajax() for a lower level solution.

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible, but you can use ajax to update content on the div(not exactly refreshing).

Edit: you can use simple javascript to complete an ajax request. In ajax a request is sent to the server which sends some data back which can be used to update the html inside the div.
www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's called `jquery`. It's a javascript library to make many functions easier to write with less code. `Ajax` is a part of it and what you use to make Http requests to get dynamic content into a div.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to reload the whole page then you may use `jQuery Ajax`.But using this you can only change the content of div tag without refreshing the whole page

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way, tell me if it works:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.post(
        "anotherpage.php",
        {"field":"value"},
        function(r){ 
            if(r!==''){ 
                $(".replace").html(r); 
            } 
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Some text</div>
    <div class="replace">Default Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is your best bet, but it isn't something exclusive to jQuery. if youre not using jQuery anyway, you will find it more efficient to write the scripts yourself instead of loading the entire jQuery library along with your site.

Answer (score 0):

It's Very Easy to Do with jQuery and PHP (AJAX), you can load new value from database or anywhere from webpage you want and also you can set the time interval do check out this link:

http://phphere.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-refresh-particular-div-in.html